# How to save django-awesome-avatar field in normal form

Tags: django

The `avatar` model field from django-awesome-avatar app extends the `ImageField` without a customized `to_python` method (see [django guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.django.db.models.SubfieldBase))

It seems to me that is only cater for `ModelForm` saving using class method `save_form_data`, but I currently have a form that covers 2 models therefore `ModelForm` will not fit in this case

See [source](https://github.com/dimka665/django-awesome-avatar/blob/master/awesome_avatar/fields.py)

Just wondering how to save the normal form data for this particular field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current hack is inside the form class save method:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(id=1)

if self.cleaned_data['avatar']['file'] is not None:
    avatar_field = AvatarField()
    avatar_field.name = 'avatar'
    avatar_field.save_form_data(profile, self.cleaned_data['avatar'])
```

Or change related code(self) if you do it outside of the form class.

Alternatively I can loop through the fields in _meta class, but it seems instantiate a new field object directly is easier.